# Converting answers into comments

Tags: discussion, comments, convert-to-comment

Often I get to review an obvious comment that was posted as an answer, because the user doesn't have the privilege yet. There are times that just flagging to delete this post is not very good, because it does actually have some suggestions to improve the answer.

So, sometimes I add this users post as a comment to the intended place (question/answer) and flag to delete as *not an answer*. Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153552/angularjs-validate-form-array-length/23875225#comment36751565_22154484), although this might also be a new question (I think I added the additional suggestion to the deleted post).

As I just now learned, diamond mods have the **power** to convert those answers to comments.

My question is: *Should I continue my practice of re-posting as comments or should I flag the post with a custom message to mod?*

The latter might be better as the user would the notified if someone responds to the comment. I think this is not possible with my approach. But there is also the possibility that the mod does not agree with me, so that the post will be deleted without living on.

Comment: It's very rare that we would use that power to convert a comment for a *new user*. Some moderators, like myself, just plain won't convert it if they don't have the privilege.

Comment: @animuson If *truly useful* information is provided, it just does not answer the question, why would you object to converting it to a comment? Seems like you're letting noble principles get in the way of the overall goal.

Comment: @CodyGray, probably because the environment here is already chasing away lots of new users. It would not be a good idea to make it worse.