# Why is a user with low reputation allowed to answer a question but not to comment the same?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

If **commenting to a question** is also for asking more required data to answer it. Shouldn't a person allowed to answer, also be allowed to comment on the  question?

Comment: Of course not. Users without the commenting privilege should simply stick to answering questions that don't need clarification to be answerable, until they've earned the few upvotes required for comments. If everyone were allowed to comment everywhere, this would open the doors for all kinds of abuse.

Comment: @l4mpi: ...such as answering questions in the comments section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's hardly abuse; I'd even say it's preferred for most of the drivel I comment on. This question, for example, is basically a FAQ - while one can answer it again and again and again, that's not exactly useful. On the bright side, your comment prompted me to look for a suitable dupe...

Comment: I agree 100% and had the same problem when I started using stackoverflow. Especially if you want to fix or improve an answer you shouldn't have to repost it as a new answer.

Comment: @l4mpi: Well, exactly. If it's a dupe, _don't_ answer it again and again and again. "It's a dupe so instead of answering it in the answer section I answered it in the comments section" does not make sense, and suggests you are treating the page as a chat room. That all being said, most of meta doesn't work as a format anyway so whatevr ;p

Comment: @ykay: That is what the suggested edits feature is for. Reposting someone else's answer with a correction made to it is _wrong anyway_. And still has nothing to do with comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry to be ignorant but how do you suggest an edit? I know I've tried to fix mistakes in code by editing but moderators told me to put in comment instead

Comment: @ykay: Are you sure they were moderators? There are lots of silly people out there who will look at a small suggested edit then encourage you to _do the wrong thing_ with it instead. So absurd.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah they deleted my code fixes and reversed the code to have the bugs :-)

Comment: @ykay - Moderators were not involved with that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154656/switching-xeditable-off-and-on-using-editabledestroy . The problem with that edit was that the typo *was* the error in your code. You asked how to solve it, and someone provided an answer that described how to do this. By editing your question to fix the typo, your question and that answer no longer made any sense. That's why the edit was rolled back, and why they left you that comment.

Comment: Aha. So, again, unrelated to this :)

Comment: @BradLarson Actually I was referring to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385838/dynamically-generate-page-linkbuttons-for-the-pagertemplate-of-a-gridview/28463582#comment47731957_28463582

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because comments are second-class citizens.

Answers end up in review queues and can be downvoted. We don't do this for comments, because comments are likely to be temporary.

The flip side of this is that comments would be easier to abuse; spammers would love to be able to spamvertize their products in comments. And a lot of opinionated, off-topic discussion would soon take place in comments if we removed the threshold.

The 50-point threshold for posting comments can be awkward if you really have something meaningful to say, but it is there for a good reason.
If it wasn't there, comments that *do* contribute value would soon be drowned in irrelevant noise. Newcomers would be using the comment section as new type of Reddit. Not out of malice, but out of ignorance. So, we require that people prove they understand a bit of how SE works, before we allow them to comment.

But yes, it can be annoying if you really have something useful to add.

Comment: I do [re-post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256250/converting-answers-into-comments) misguided answers as comments if they are *meaningful*. Then I flag the answer as NaA and comment that I re-posted the comment.

Comment: It's not 'annoying' if you really have something meaningful to say. It's detrimental to the site because of the lost useful content. It's also discouraging to new users who want to brave the waters with a comment or two here and there before going for a question/answer.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your answer. First, the a comment can be very good to the poster, but if posted as answer, it would be downvoted. I've seen it countless times. Then, the website forces you to make reputation to help others. Second, if I give my reputation for a bounty and go beneath 50 reputation, I loose the posibiltiy to post any comment, which is very bad. I don't have anything with you, but I give you a -1.

Comment: It's fair to disagree, @machineaddict. Regarding bounties, it has been suggested that people keep their privileges when offering bounties - but that request was largely voted against, IIRC.